# Get color of a scatter point

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot with some toy data.

I want to draw a label next to a given point with the color of the point.

Toy example:

```
x = 100*np.random.rand(5,1)
y = 100*np.random.rand(5,1)
c = np.random.rand(5,1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, cmap='viridis')

# I want to annotate the third point (idx=2)
idx = 2  
ax.annotate("hello", xy=(x[idx],y[idx]), color='green', 
            xytext=(5,5), textcoords="offset points")
plt.show()
```

[image]

I need to somehow get the color of this point and change my `color='green'` part for `color=color_of_the_point`

How can I get the color of a point in a scatter plot?

The color vector `c` is transformed to a colormap, and it can also have further modifications such as normalization or alpha value.

sc has a method for retrieving the coordinates of the points:

```
sc.get_offsets()
```

So it would be logical to also have a method for getting the color of the points but I could not find such method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The scatter plot is a `PathCollection`, which subclasses `ScalarMappable`. A `ScalarMappable` has a method `to_rgba`. This can be used to get the color corresponding to the colorvalues.

In this case

```
sc.to_rgba(c[idx])
```

Note that the arrays used in the question are 2D arrays, which is normally undesired. So a complete example would look like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = 100*np.random.rand(5)
y = 100*np.random.rand(5)
c = np.random.rand(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, cmap='viridis')

# I want to annotate the third point (idx=2)
idx = 2  
ax.annotate("hello", xy=(x[idx],y[idx]), color=sc.to_rgba(c[idx]), 
            xytext=(5,5), textcoords="offset points")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The scatter plot is a `PathCollection` as mentioned by the other answer. It has a `get_facecolors()` method which returns the color used to render each point. However, the correct colors are only returned once the scatter plot is rendered. So, we can first trigger a `plt.draw()` and then use `get_facecolors()`.

Working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = 100*np.random.rand(5)
y = 100*np.random.rand(5)
c = np.random.rand(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(x, y, c=c, cmap='viridis')

idx = 2  
plt.draw()

col = sc.get_facecolors()[idx].tolist()

ax.annotate("hello", xy=(x[idx],y[idx]), color=col, 
            xytext=(5,5), textcoords="offset points")
plt.show()
```

which generates

[image: Example Plot]