# Getting data of scatter plot other than x,y data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

In python, suppose that I were to plot a scatter plot as follows,

```
sc = plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, c=color_vector, s=size_vector, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
```

I know I can get `x_data, y_data` from `sc` using `sc.get_offsets()`, but how about the values `color_vector, size_vector`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908429/get-color-of-a-scatter-point

Comment: I don't think so. If I'm understanding that question correctly, it seems to return the `cmap(norm(color_vector))`, but I would like to obtain the `color_vector`. For example, if `color_vector = [1,2,3,4,5]`, how would I obtain this from `sc`.

Comment: @AndrewYuan I am curious why you want to get the values this way? since you are plotting the data can't you take data directly from color_vector?

Comment: I'm trying to write a class so that if my mouse hovers over a scattered point, it will show the corresponding color value/size value. I know that I can just have `color_vector, size_vector` as my inputs when first initializing the class, but I would prefer to have `sc` as my only argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `sc.get_sizes()` and `sc.get_array()` will do the trick.